# Spring boot @PathVariable Validation

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my controller I have a ethod annotated by GetMapping and I want to validate the path variable. I tested the @max and @min. they were ok. but the thing is when I want to check when no path variable is not passed, I get 404 error code. meaning that i want to test the case like:

http://localhost:9090/api/mancala-game/last-state/

where there is nothing after the last /.

I want to get the exception in my ExceptionHandler class.

any ideas?
thank you

Comment: the happy scenario is like : http://localhost:9090/api/mancala-game/last-state/9d5d96e1-6035-493a-9239-06e48f07600a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send path variable , in the url it self otherwise you will throw 404 error .
when your are not sending path variable it will be a different API:
in your case :  http://localhost:9090/api/mancala-game/last-state/
and this url is not pointing to any handling method in your controller, So you will get 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I think `http://localhost:9090/api/mancala-game/last-state/` and

`http://localhost:9090/api/mancala-game/last-state/{key}` is two api.

you can create `/last-state` and `/last-state/{key}`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add a wildcard `**` at the end of the REST endpoint `api/mancala-game/last-state/` at the place where you call the `antMatchers()` method for this REST endpoint. For example:

```
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "api/mancala-game/last-state/**").permitAll() //Other antMatchers after this..
```